# App works fine in Debug mode but crashes when running directly

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

I'm working on an Android app developing project, and I'm stuck with a strange situation which is seems to be caused by the constructor of CursorLoader.
My app works fine in debug mode, but crashes when it runs without debugging.
How can I fix this?

Great thanks in advance

**Code:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.tee.quietime;

import ...;
//All imports needed

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.tee.quietime.MESSAGE";

    eventsListAdapter adapter;
    protected static GregorianCalendar selectedDate;
    protected static TextView selectedDateTxt;
    protected static TextView emptyText;
    protected static CalendarView mainCalendar;
    protected static ListView selectedDateEventsList;
    private static final TimeZone defaultTZ=TimeZone.getDefault();
    private static final int INSTANCES_LOADER = 0;
    private static final String ID_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances._ID;
    private static final String BEGIN_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN;
    private static final String END_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances.END;
    private static final String END_DAY_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances.END_DAY;
    private static final String END_MINUTE_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances.END_MINUTE;
    private static final String EVENT_ID_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_ID;
    private static final String START_DAY_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances.START_DAY;
    private static final String START_MINUTE_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances.START_MINUTE;
    private static final String ALL_DAY_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances.ALL_DAY;
    private static final String DURATION_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances.DURATION;
    private static final String LOCATION_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_LOCATION;
    private static final String TITLE_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances.TITLE;
    private static final String TIMEZONE_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_TIMEZONE;
    private static final String END_TIMEZONE_COLNAME = CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_END_TIMEZONE;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Setting Selected Date for today and updating Text
        selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) Calendar.getInstance();
        selectedDateTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selectedDate);
        this.updateSelectedDateTxt();

        selectedDateEventsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.EventList);
        emptyText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.noEventsTxt);
        selectedDateEventsList.setEmptyView(emptyText);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(INSTANCES_LOADER, null, this);   

        mainCalendar = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.mainCalendar);

        //Previous Date onClickListener
        ImageButton previousDate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previousDate);
        previousDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ...
                updateSelectedDateList();
            }
        });


        //Next Date onClickListener
        ImageButton nextDate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextDate);
        nextDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ...
                updateSelectedDateList();
            }
        });


        //Go to Today onClickListener
        ImageButton goToToday = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.goToToday);
        goToToday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ...
                updateSelectedDateList();
            }
        });


        //Changing date on calendar listener
        mainCalendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                ...
                updateSelectedDateList();
            }
        });





    }

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)  {
            switch (id){
            case INSTANCES_LOADER:{     
                                        Uri baseUri=Instances.CONTENT_URI;
                                        final String[] INSTANCE_PROJECTION= new String[] {Instances._ID,
                                                                                          Instances.BEGIN,
                                                                                          Instances.END,
                                                                                          Instances.END_DAY,
                                                                                          Instances.END_MINUTE,
                                                                                          Instances.EVENT_ID,
                                                                                          Instances.START_DAY,
                                                                                          Instances.START_MINUTE,
                                                                                          Instances.ALL_DAY,
                                                                                          Instances.DURATION,
                                                                                          Instances.EVENT_LOCATION,
                                                                                          Instances.TITLE,
                                                                                          Instances.EVENT_TIMEZONE,
                                                                                          Instances.EVENT_END_TIMEZONE,
                                                                            };
                                        String selection = "((" + Instances.VISIBLE + " = ? ) AND (" + Instances.END + " < ? ) AND (" + Instances.BEGIN + " >= ? ))";
                                        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"1",String.valueOf(selectedDate.getTimeInMillis()+86400000),String.valueOf(selectedDate.getTimeInMillis())};
//////////               CRASHES HERE !!                ///////////                             
                                        return new CursorLoader(this,baseUri,INSTANCE_PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, Instances.BEGIN); 

            }
            default:return null;

            }
        }




    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        switch(cursorLoader.getId()){

            case INSTANCES_LOADER :{    
                                    int i=0,size=0;
                                    for(cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast();cursor.moveToNext()) size++;
                                    String[][] values= new String[size][5];
                                    for(cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast();cursor.moveToNext()){
                                        values[i][0]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TITLE_COLNAME));
                                        values[i][1]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LOCATION_COLNAME));
                                        values[i][2]=String.valueOf(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BEGIN_COLNAME)))+defaultTZ.getRawOffset());
                                        values[i][3]=String.valueOf(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(END_COLNAME)))+defaultTZ.getRawOffset());
                                        values[i][4]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ALL_DAY_COLNAME));
                                        i++;
                                    }
                                    adapter = new eventsListAdapter(this,values);
                                    selectedDateEventsList.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }

    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
        cursorLoader=null;

    }

    protected void updateSelectedDateTxt(){
    ...
    }

    protected void updateSelectedDateCalendar(){
    ...
    }

    protected void updateSelectedDateList(){ 
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(INSTANCES_LOADER, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ...
    }
```

**eventsListAdapter (Custom Adapter)**

```
package com.tee.quietime;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class eventsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> {
    private final Context context;
      private final String[][] values;

      public eventsListAdapter(Context context, String[][] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.eventrowlayout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventrowlayout, parent, false);
        TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        TextView subTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);

        String titleOnly= values[position][0];
        if (values[position][1]!=null && !values[position][1].isEmpty()){
            String titleWithLocation =titleOnly + " at "+values[position][1];
            title.setText(titleWithLocation);
            }
        else 
            title.setText(titleOnly);

        long millisST=Long.parseLong(values[position][2]);
        long millisEND=Long.parseLong(values[position][3]);

        String strST=String.format("%02d:%02d", 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisST)%24,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisST) -  
                TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisST)));

        String strEND=String.format("%02d:%02d", 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisEND)%24,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisEND) -  
                TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisEND)));

        String subTxt="Starts "+strST+" - "+strEND;
        String subTxtAllDay="All day event";
        if(values[position][4].compareTo("1")!=0)
            subTitle.setText(subTxt);
        else 
            subTitle.setText(subTxtAllDay);

        return rowView;
      }
    }
```

**LogCat**

```
12-02 00:08:12.265: D/OpenGLRenderer(30687): Enabling debug mode 0
12-02 00:08:12.475: D/dalvikvm(30687): threadid=11: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
12-02 00:08:17.355: W/dalvikvm(30687): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4162aba8)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687): Process: com.tee.quietime, PID: 30687
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar/instances/when
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:413)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:461)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:65)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:43)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-02 00:08:17.365: E/AndroidRuntime(30687):    ... 3 more
```

Comment: read stacktrace after crash

Comment: **Answer:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273061/getting-a-calendar-events-instances