# How to get calendar events with title including recurring events

Tags: android, calendar

I need to do a not complicated thing, one could believe. I want to get Event instances from calendars on my phone along with titles of the events. I found several answers on Stack Overflow telling to query `Instances` table to get recurring events also, which I did, but I can't figure out how to get Event names from this query, because they are in `Events` table. I found no example of how to do this. I tried to create a custom query by joining Events with Instances, but I don't know if it's even possible to query Calendar tables like this (bypassing API).

Do anybody know how to simply get all `Event.TITLE`, `Instance.DTSTART` for given start and end dates?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I probably need to get some sleep...

`Instances` table has column `CalendarContract.Instances.TITLE` which holds the title even though it's not in the `Instances` table. The query hits some `View` not the `Instances` table. I would swear I tried this way and couldn't find `TITLE` in intellisense for columns.

Full solution here for anybody who may find this useful:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.now().withTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime endDate = startDate.plusDays(7);

Uri.Builder eventsUriBuilder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI
            .buildUpon();
ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, startDate.getMillis());
ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, endDate.getMillis());

Uri eventsUri = eventsUriBuilder.build();
Cursor cursor = null;
cursor = getContentResolver().query(
        eventsUri,
        new String[] {CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART, CalendarContract.Instances.TITLE},
        CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART + " >= " + startDate.getMillis() + " and " + CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART + " <= " + endDate.getMillis() + " and " + CalendarContract.Instances.VISIBLE + " = 1",
        null,
        CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART + " ASC");
```

This code is using [Joda time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Answer (score 0):

This code return all events(recurring events)
just  add the code in your code
" CalendarContract.Instances.VISIBLE + " = 0" +" or "+CalendarContract.Instances.VISIBLE + " = 1" "

it returns all events in a year.

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.now().withTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime endDate = startDate.plusDays(360);

Uri.Builder eventsUriBuilder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI
        .buildUpon();
ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder,startOfDay.getTimeInMillis());
ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, endDate.getMillis());

Uri eventsUri = eventsUriBuilder.build();
Cursor cursor = null;
cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        eventsUri,
        new String[]{CalendarContract.Instances.CALENDAR_ID, CalendarContract.Instances.TITLE, CalendarContract.Instances.DESCRIPTION, CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN, CalendarContract.Instances.END, CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_LOCATION, CalendarContract.Instances.ORIGINAL_ID, CalendarContract.Instances.ORGANIZER, CalendarContract.Instances.OWNER_ACCOUNT},
        CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN + " >= " + .getTimeInMillis()+ " and "+CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN + " <= " + endDate.getMillis()+" and " + CalendarContract.Instances.VISIBLE + " = 0" +" or "+CalendarContract.Instances.VISIBLE + " = 1",
        null,
        CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN + " ASC");
```

Comment: You also should state what your code does as it is not a one-liner and not just copy paste here...